# angular pass attribute to the component when the component is used in the template

Tags: angular

I have a component that use a service to fetch a menu configuration from a rest-api server:

**the service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export class Menu {

}

@Injectable()
export class MenuService {
  private _wpAng = environment.wpAng;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getMenu(menu) {
    return this.http.get(this._wpAng + `menu/${menu}`);
  }

}
```

So here I have to pass a `menu` string to fetch this menu configuration:

**the component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from './menus.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menus',
  templateUrl: './menus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menus.component.scss'],
  providers: [MenuService]
})
export class MenusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private menuService: MenuService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuService.getMenu('main-menu').subscribe((menu => console.log(menu)),(err =>'main-menu don`t exist'))
  }

}
```

Here I get the `main-menu` configuration, and all works fine.

The problem is when I have more than one menu. And I want to use the same component in different parts of the main view. So my problem is how to pass the menu identification when the component is loaded in the view? For example I need something like:

```
to use the main-menu
<app-menus menu='main-menu'></app-menus>

to use other-menu
<app-menus menu='other-menu'></app-menus>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some `@Input` to your `MenusComponent`.

See following link for example: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/passing_data_into_components.html